# Open new instance of C# windows application

Tags: c#, window, instance

I am working in windows environment and I need to open a new instance of my application programmatically while running the application is that possible?

I am greatly appreciative of any guidance or help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
var info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(Application.ExecutablePath);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info );
```

Comment: Again, don't hard-code the path. Even just the path to the EXE. Two reasons: 1) The name of the EXE is likely to change, and the resulting bug will be difficult to detect without extensive testing. 2) There's no guarantee that the working directory will always be the application's root directory for the duration of the program's execution. You don't want to rely on this being the case.

Comment: Changed to Application.ExecutablePath

Comment: Is there a way to do this in monodevelop? There is no static variable named `Application.ExecutablePath`

Comment: If you're using Monodevelop, use the following code:
`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);`

Answer (score 8):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

For a Winforms App.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method:

```
Process.Start(@"c:\work\myapp\foo.exe");
```

and if your application needed to take arguments:

```
Process.Start(@"c:\work\myapp\foo.exe", "-a arg1 -b arg2");
```

Comment: Yeah, but definitely don't hard-code the path. (I realize this is probably for example purposes only, but it bears repeating anyway.)

Comment: @Cody Gray, sure, it's better for the path to be externalized.

Answer (score 2):

You can start any application using the [`Process.Start()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92699yzt.aspx) method.

But depending on what you want to do, it might be better to directly use classes from your one of your applications to e.g . open window that's in another application.

Answer (score 1):

Sure! You have create a new istance of your main project class!

You have to create a reference to your project and then you can create your main form istances!

**Updated**

My mistake! I've understand that you have to call a second existing application from a first one.

Comment: What's a “main project class”?